# JavaCard returns SW=`6A80` in the KoreanSEED-algorithm-containing applet installation process

Tags: javacard

I wrote the below Java Card applet to do a *Korean SEED* encryption/decryption in my *JCOP v2.4.2 r3* Java Card:

```java
public class CryptoKoreanSeed extends Applet {

    //Abbreviations
    private static final boolean NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS = false;

    // Array for the encryption/decryption key
    private byte[] the_Key = new byte[128];

    // Defining required key
    KoreanSEEDKey koreanSeedKey = (KoreanSEEDKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_KOREAN_SEED, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_KOREAN_SEED_128, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);

    // Defining required cipher
    Cipher myCipher;

    // Defining switch case variables for supported instructions = INS in APDU command
    final byte SET_KEY = (byte) 0xC0;
    final byte DO_CRYPTO = (byte) 0xC2;

    // Defining switch case variables for cipher algorithms = P1 in APDU command
    final byte ALG_KOREAN_SEED_CBC_NOPAD = (byte) 0x00;
    final byte ALG_KOREAN_SEED_ECB_NOPAD = (byte) 0x01;

    // Defining switch case variables for crytptography mode = P2 in APDU command
    final byte ENCRYPT_MODE = (byte) 0x00;
    final byte DECRYPT_MODE = (byte) 0x01;

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        new CryptoKoreanSeed();
    }

    protected CryptoKoreanSeed() {
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        // Checking the CLA field in the APDU command.
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

        // Checking the P1 and P2 fields in the APDU command.
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] != 0x00 || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] > 1) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
        }

        try {

            switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

                case SET_KEY:
                    setCryptoKeyAndInitCipher(apdu);
                    break;

                case DO_CRYPTO:
                    doIt(apdu);
                    break;

                default:
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }

        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(((CryptoException) e).getReason());
        }

    }

    public void setCryptoKeyAndInitCipher(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        // Key must has 16 bytes length
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 16) {
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, the_Key,
                    (short) 0, buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC]);
            koreanSeedKey.setKey(the_Key, (short) 0);

        } else {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
        }

    }

    public void doIt(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]) {
            case ALG_KOREAN_SEED_CBC_NOPAD:
                myCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_KOREAN_SEED_CBC_NOPAD, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
                break;
            case ALG_KOREAN_SEED_ECB_NOPAD:
                myCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_KOREAN_SEED_ECB_NOPAD, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
                break;
        }

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == ENCRYPT_MODE) {
            myCipher.init(koreanSeedKey, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == DECRYPT_MODE) {
            myCipher.init(koreanSeedKey, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);
        }

        byte[] CipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 32,
                JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

        short datalen = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
        if ((datalen % 16) != 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
        }

        short cipheredDataLength = myCipher.doFinal(buffer, (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, datalen, CipheredData, (short) 0);
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(CipheredData, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
                cipheredDataLength);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, cipheredDataLength);
    }
}
```

The above program successfully compiled and now I have its *.CAP* file. The problem is I can't Install it on my card and it returns the following error:

```java
GP:gp -install C:\CapFiles\cryptoKoreanSeed.cap -d -v
# Detected readers from SunPCSC
[*] ACS CCID USB Reader 0
SCardConnect("ACS CCID USB Reader 0", T=*) -> T=1, 3BF91300008131FE454A434F50323
4325233A2
SCardBeginTransaction("ACS CCID USB Reader 0")
Reader: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
ATR: 3BF91300008131FE454A434F503234325233A2
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3BF91300008131FE454A434F503234325
233A2

#Unnecessary data censored

CAP file (v2.1) generated on Mon May 25 16:37:28 IRDT 2015
By Sun Microsystems Inc. converter  [v3.0.2] with JDK 1.7.0_51 (Oracle Corporati
on)
Package: cryptoPack v1.0 with AID 0102030405CCDD
Applet: CryptoKoreanSeed with AID 0102030405CC
Import: A0000000620101 v1.4
Import: A0000000620102 v1.4
Import: A0000000620201 v1.4
Import: A0000000620001 v1.0
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28000 0A 4F00ECF134B96E7CBB78 00
A<< (0011+2) (45ms) 08A000000151000000019E 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F24000 0A 4F00D10F9CAEA700B12D 00
A<< (0000+2) (41ms) 6A88
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F22000 0A 4F00B7CFF545BD7B18FE 00
A<< (0010+2) (45ms) 07A00000015153500100 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21000 0A 4F00D90A8E14640EF9C2 00
A<< (0020+2) (49ms) 07A000000151535001000108A000000151535041 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0028) 84E60200 1C 070102030405CCDD08A0000001510000000000006BDFA77872F
60FBB
A<< (0001+2) (63ms) 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80000 FF C482029B010011DECAFFED0102040001070102030405CCDD020
01F0011001F000A0029007600100158000A0035000000F900000000000004010004002904040107A
0000000620101040107A0000000620102040107A0000000620201000107A000000062000103000A0
1060102030405CC000906001000800309000307030000005100AA00D707015801007B802400A1000
E02308F000B3D8C00173B7A0410188C000C18110080900B8700181012110080038D00099400000A8
7011810C088021810C2880318038804180488051803880618048807188B000D7A0222188B000F600
37A198B00102D1A03256008116E008D00111A052561EBE3A20880932DD0
A<< (0001+2) (235ms) 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0255) 84E80001 FF 081A0625046F08116A868D00111A042575001B0002FFC0000DF
FC2001418198B0012700F18198B00137008116D008D0011700A2E1B8B00148D00117A0621198B001
02D1A072510106B101A08AD00031A07258D00153B70081169848D0011AD01AD00038E03000A047A0
624198B00102D1A052575002100020000000D00010018181011038D00168708700B181010038D001
687081A0625610CAD08AD01058B001870101A0625046B0AAD08AD01048B00181020058D00192E198
B001A2904160410104960081169848D0011AD081A0816041B038B001B29051B031A0316058D00153
B190316058B001C7A08000A0000000000000000000057F60CE63453B2C0
A<< (0001+2) (138ms) 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0185) 84E88002 B9 050076001D02000000020000010200000302000004020000050
200000602000007020000080200000206810D000181180001000000068003000380030101810C000
380030303800A0106800701030000080300000903810C01068010020682010006000014038201030
680080D03800A060382010103800A0809003500122110050504040404701202270B07020E0220001
F0705040812042007070C1115070807030713090908180B0F1006050F0B0B08A95A9A81358AFC7D
A<< (0001+2) (653ms) 9000
CAP loaded
A>> T=1 (4+0036) 84E60C00 24 070102030405CCDD060102030405CC060102030405CC010002C
90000D862593AAEA7F2F2
A<< (0000+2) (1s497ms) 6A80
pro.javacard.gp.GPException: Install for Install and make selectable failed SW:
6A80
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.check(GlobalPlatform.java:1092)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.installAndMakeSelectable(GlobalPlatfor
m.java:798)
        at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:478)
```

**What's the origin of this `6A80` error?**

As a side question: Is there any online tools or library to compare the output of card for this applet (result of my applet) with the output of that tool/library? I already checked *OpenSSL* and it seems that there is no module in it for KOREAN SEED algorithm.

I appreciate all your comments to make the program more efficient.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update1: Modified program based on comments**

```java
public class CryptoKoreanSeed extends Applet {

    //Abbreviations
    private static final boolean NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS = false;

    // Array for the encryption/decryption key
    private byte[] the_Key = new byte[128];

    // Defining required key
    KoreanSEEDKey koreanSeedKey;

    // Defining required cipher
    Cipher myCipher;

    // Defining switch case variables for supported instructions = INS in APDU command
    final byte SET_KEY = (byte) 0xC0;
    final byte DO_CRYPTO = (byte) 0xC2;

    // Defining switch case variables for cipher algorithms = P1 in APDU command
    final byte ALG_KOREAN_SEED_CBC_NOPAD = (byte) 0x00;
    final byte ALG_KOREAN_SEED_ECB_NOPAD = (byte) 0x01;

    // Defining switch case variables for crytptography mode = P2 in APDU command
    final byte ENCRYPT_MODE = (byte) 0x00;
    final byte DECRYPT_MODE = (byte) 0x01;

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        try {
            new CryptoKoreanSeed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x8888);
        }
    }

    protected CryptoKoreanSeed() {
        register();
        koreanSeedKey = (KoreanSEEDKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_KOREAN_SEED, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_KOREAN_SEED_128, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);

    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        // Checking the CLA field in the APDU command.
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

        // Checking the P1 and P2 fields in the APDU command.
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] > 0x01 || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] > 0x01) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
        }

        try {

            switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

                case SET_KEY:
                    setCryptoKeyAndInitCipher(apdu);
                    break;

                case DO_CRYPTO:
                    doIt(apdu);
                    break;

                default:
                    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }

        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(((CryptoException) e).getReason());
        }

    }

    public void setCryptoKeyAndInitCipher(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        // Key must has 16 bytes length
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 16) {
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, the_Key,
                    (short) 0, buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC]);
            koreanSeedKey.setKey(the_Key, (short) 0);

        } else {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
        }

    }

    public void doIt(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]) {
            case ALG_KOREAN_SEED_CBC_NOPAD:
                myCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_KOREAN_SEED_CBC_NOPAD, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
                break;
            case ALG_KOREAN_SEED_ECB_NOPAD:
                myCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_KOREAN_SEED_ECB_NOPAD, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
                break;
        }

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == ENCRYPT_MODE) {
            myCipher.init(koreanSeedKey, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == DECRYPT_MODE) {
            myCipher.init(koreanSeedKey, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);
        }

        byte[] CipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 32,
                JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

        short datalen = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
        if ((datalen % 16) != 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
        }

        short cipheredDataLength = myCipher.doFinal(buffer, (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, datalen, CipheredData, (short) 0);
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(CipheredData, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
                cipheredDataLength);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, cipheredDataLength);
    }
}
```

**Q:** The above applet installed successfully on my card. Now, The question is "If my card doesn't support *KOREAN SEED* algorithm (while it is mentioned that it support it in the card's manual), so **why the card doesn't throw `0x8888` in the installation process now (while I throw this status word in the `catch` scope in the constructor)?" Doesn't constructor called in the installation step?**

This is output of the installed applet :

```java
OSC:: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a40400060102030405CC -s 00C00000100011223344556677889
9AABBCCDDEEFF -s 00c200001001000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f -s 00c200011001000
102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f -s 00c201001001000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f -s
 00c201011001000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 06 01 02 03 04 05 CC
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C0 00 00 10 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF
Received (SW1=0x6F, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C2 00 00 10 01 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x03)
Sending: 00 C2 00 01 10 01 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x03)
Sending: 00 C2 01 00 10 01 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x03)
Sending: 00 C2 01 01 10 01 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x03)
```

---

As a side question : Which one is correct? and why?

1:

```
    protected CryptoKoreanSeed() {
        register();
        koreanSeedKey = (KoreanSEEDKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_KOREAN_SEED, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_KOREAN_SEED_128, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
    }
```

2:

```
    protected CryptoKoreanSeed() {
        koreanSeedKey = (KoreanSEEDKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_KOREAN_SEED, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_KOREAN_SEED_128, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);
        register();   
    }
```

Comment: I hope I hadn't a silly mistake just like the previous times! :D

Comment: I think it is quite clear: `KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_KOREAN_SEED, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_KOREAN_SEED_128, ...)` throws `CryptoException` of reason `NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM`. Please surround it with a try-catch block (if you catch the exception, the applet will be installable). *General rule:* an uncaught exception (not an instance of `ISOException`, of course) results to `6F00` in the standard APDU processing (`process()` method) and to `6A80` during the installation (`install()` method).

Comment: A few more suggestions: `buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] > 1` is problematic: values from `0x80` to `0xFF` are cast to **signed** integer, which means your condition will not work for these values. Use `(buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] & 0xFF)` instead.

Comment: `(datalen % 16) != 0` could be done in a faster way: `(datalen & 0x0F != 0)`, but It is surely not the most important improvement :-)

Comment: @vojta Thank you very much for your comments dear vojta. As far as I know I can't use _try-catch_ outside of methods (I'll receive `illegal start of type` if I do it). Does your comment mean I must move `KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_KOREAN_SEED, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_KOREAN_SEED_128, ...)` inside a method and then surround it with _try-catch_? if so, which one of the methods?

Comment: the instance of Key is created in the constructor of your applet. The cunstructor is invoked in the install method. You can surround the constructor inside the install method with try-catch.

Comment: @vojta I did the same and now the applet installed without throwing any error while I was added `ISOException.throwIt((short)0x8888);` in the `catch` body. Shouldn't I receive 0x8888 instead of 0x6a80?

Comment: Moreover, in the manual of my card it is mentioned that the card is supporting this algorithm, so why I need to this try-catch?

Comment: @vojta Ah, As I added `koreanSeedKey = (KoreanSEEDKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_KOREAN_SEED, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_KOREAN_SEED_128, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);` after calling `register()` method in the constructor, I think it isn't called in the installation process. (i.e I think it is `unreachable statement`). When I move it to the line before `register()` method, I received `0x6a80` error again! (While the constructor in the install method is surrounded with try-catch)

Comment: It is difficult for me to imagine how your source code looks like now. Could you please post it?

Comment: @vojta sure. Do I must update the previous code or add it as a new one in the end of question?

Comment: Is `register()` in its right place in the constructor or I must to move it after `koreanSeedKey = (KoreanSEEDKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_KOREAN_SEED, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_KOREAN_SEED_128, NO_EXTERNAL_ACCESS);`? Is there any difference? When I moved `register()` to the line after above line, I received the first error (i.e `0x6a80`) in the installation process again.

Comment: I think you should not call `register` in the constructor, because the instance does not exist yet. You should call it from the `install` method: `(new CryptoKoreanSeed()).register();`

Comment: @vojta I did it in all of my previous applets and they worked successfully until now, so I don't think it is the origin of error. Can we have a short conversation in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78946/discussion-between-vojta-and-abraham).